# Crashed alien ship AI upgrades a human to become the ship captain it needs for full function

Tags: story-identification, novel

Recent Kindle novel--Its alien Captain left the crashed ship to explore millennia ago and never returned, concealed alien ship AI cannot initiate any action without a biological Captain so, ship AI attracts and upgrades a passing high potential human to become the ship captain it needs for full function.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: This was the plot of one episode of the Planetary comic.

Answer (score 9):

This might be *[Mutineer's Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutineers%27_Moon)*, by David Weber. The AI of a large ship that is pretending to be our moon kidnaps a passing astronaut. It upgrades him biologically, and forces him to become its captain. The ship can't take any action to resolve its problems; it requires a human to make decisions.

[image: Front cover of Mutineer's Moon]

Comment: That was my first thought when I saw the question.

Comment: Small correction if I might, Dahak can take independent decisions and implement them without human supervision as long as they comply with her last order "kill the mutineers". Her problem is all her options imply Doomsday for humanity, so she needs somebody to work with her to open them up. Making the passign astronaut her Captain is a commodity to make available resources which are only accessible to the Ship's Captain.

Answer (score 5):

[First of my Kind](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/38342744-first-of-my-kind) (2017) by Marc Stevens is about a guy who gets stranded in Alaska but rescued by a stranded ship AI.

It upgrades his body with alien procedures and they end up leaving Earth to locate the ship's missing pieces and to stop the galactic corruption that led to the ship originally being stranded in the first place.

He is tricked into it but accepts (after the fact) that he is the ship's biological crew member/captain

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm reading this series and have reached the end of the current "episode."

It's Starship Sakira (Delphi in Space book 1, from the [Amazon listing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0812822L3):

> What would you do if you found a spaceship? Would you call the
> government, would you pretend you never saw it, or would you keep it a
> secret? What would you do with it? Use it to gallivant around the
> galaxy, conquer Earth, get filthy rich, or try to improve life on
> Earth? Read along and find out how Marc McCormack handles his
> discovery of a starship. How strives to convert Earth into a
> spacefaring world capable of defending itself before it meets the
> other civilizations in the galaxy. His dream, a united Earth at the
> forefront of an interstellar civilization. He and his brother start
> planning their next steps, but the one they don’t know how to prepare
> for is the arrival of Marc’s twelve-year-old daughter. She comes to
> spend the summer with her father. She’s very smart and extremely
> curious. Marc and his crew need to accomplish all this without tipping
> off the U.S. Government and before the Paraxeans come looking for
> their spaceship. But they have help, the ship’s AI is on their side,
> and she’s smart.

The closest I can get to the "upgrade" aspect of the question is that the AI provides nanites or nanobots (can't recall) to increase various characteristics of the new captain.

The previous captain's status in detail also escapes my alleged mind, but providing what I remember would represent a spoiler.

[image: book cover]

Answer (score 2):

This could be a partial match to "*[The Tommyknockers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tommyknockers)*" by Stephen King.

This is essentially a horror story about a man who uncovers a part of an unexpected large metal object in the woods. The object tuns out to be a spaceship which releases a gas into the air, slowly turning him (and IIRC neighbours) into creatures similar to those who piloted the crashed ship.  The story end with the almost fully transitioned man launching the ship into space telepathically and the clean-up that results.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Broken Galaxy by Phil Huddleston. Alien spaceship crashes on earth, spends a long time buried in mud until discovered by a guy on a wilderness track who digs it up and restores it to working order with the help of some friends.